# How to add an own struct_info.json? (emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c, struct, emscripten

I would like to port a C library. There is a really short tutorial about it here: [Interacting with code](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-c-in-javascript)

I need to create a struct using javascript, and return a pointer to it. I looked into the libraries, which are already ported. My code looks like this:

```
var ptr = _malloc({{{ C_STRUCTS.MyStruct.__size__ }}});

{{{ makeSetValue('ptr', C_STRUCTS.MyStruct.attr, '0', 'i8') }}};
```

It does not work, because emscripten does not know about `MyStruct`.

My library definition is added to the project using `--js-library`
But I don't know, how to add a struct definition (`struct_info.json`)

In the C code, I have:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int8_t attr;
    //...
}
```

Comment: I don't know about emscripten but can't you create a `createMyStruct` function in C and use it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option. The `MyStruct_Create` function has to be implemented in js

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904273/struct-operations-in-javascript-through-emscripten

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I would like to access data using the emscripten macros like `makeSetValue`, and not by working on the memory buffer directly

Comment: @IterAtor Let me get this straight:you would like to export your C struct right? And be able to use it from JS? Have you tried EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_value_example) {
    value_array<MyStruct>("MyStruct")
        .element(&MyStruct::attr)
        ...
?

Comment: I guess you properly exported the struct, for example with EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS.... right?

Comment: Have you already written a struct_info.json file? Maybe you can use the following: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tools/gen_struct_info.py,
which seems the tool emscripten itself uses to generate that kind of info either taking a raw C header file or an input json file (what they claim). The struct_info.json is used in the emscripten itself as you can see and they use the C structs it throughout the code in the way you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create C but not JS struct. For example:

```
var st_t = new ctypes.StructType("st_t",
        [ { "self": ctypes.PointerType(ctypes.void_t) },
        { "str": ctypes.PointerType(ctypes.char) },
        { "buff_size": ctypes.size_t },
        { "i": ctypes.int },
        { "f": ctypes.float },
        { "c": ctypes.char } ]);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: The struct is already defined in C. But the JS code can't see it, because the struct info was not provided

Comment: JS has specific functions to define external C structs.